# Package installation pycharm

Tags: python3, pycharm

I'm having a problem with pycharm packages, because they are installed. If I list them, they are installed.  When I try to use pandas I get this error:

> Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
>   ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

But the package is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Anaconda? Try [PyCharm 2019.1 EAP build](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/), the issue should be resolved there: [PY-32366](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32366).

Comment: Thank you for the help, I solved my problem :)